# Can I add extra disk storage for a Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, azure-storage

I am researching if the Azure platform is suited for my web app.

I successfully created the Web App. The Web App in question is a Service App consisting of an WebAPI, Web Site and a DB.

As for the price tier, I chosen basic, because the throughput of the API itself is minimal. Does't take a lot of space and doesn't require high performance.

But...
I do need to store some images.

Since they can get quite big, (native BMP for analyzes), I would like to add additional storage to this app without the requirements to upgrade the throughput and performance.

So, I configured a 1TB disk, but I can't see a way to give the WebApp access to this disk.

When I try to give access in IAM of the disk, I choose the option `Azure AD user, group, or application`. But it doens't find my web application.

I must say, the resource group is not the same. Is this important?

In general, is this a valid way to add pure storage to a web app?

Or, if not, can you advise me on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to use either .Net, Java, C++, Python to connect storage with your Web App.

A sample from the documentation on using JAVA:

> it is possible to write simple applications that access the Azure File
>   share using the standard Java I/O classes. This article will describe
>   how to write applications that use the Azure Storage Java SDK, which
>   uses the Azure Files REST API to talk to Azure Files.

The full documentation can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage

On the side of the link, you will find the other languages that are supported.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add extra disk storage for a Azure Web App?

The answer is no. Currently, Azure Web App does not support mount a data disk(VHD).

As Adam Smith said, you have many choices. You could store your files in Azure storage account and [storage account API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Azure-Storage-Services-REST-API-Reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to use them.

Comment: The thing is, after some research, I was able to give the app rights on the disk (at IAM level). I am not sure if I can map it from the application. I check this later this week and get back to you on this.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, Azure web app does not support mount vhd(blob) or a file share.